# Looping in Android Media Player

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play and audio file in media player and once the file is completely played then loop from a certain position from that specific file and keep on repeating the loop.

I have seen a method seekTo() which plays from a specific point but I am confused of how to first play the file completely and then use the seekTo function.

Any help would be appreciated. Sudo code will help a well.

**Adding Code:**

**Here is the code that I have tried *but it leaves a gap for about one second* before playing the sound again.**

```
public void playBackgroundMusic() {
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = null;
    try {
        descriptor = context.getAssets().openFd("music/" + FILE_NAME);
        try {
            this.mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                    descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            this.mediaPlayer.reset();
            this.mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                    descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        }
        if (listener != null) {
            this.mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(listener);
        }
        this.mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
        this.mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        this.mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        this.mediaPlayer.prepare();
        this.mediaPlayer.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (descriptor != null) {
                descriptor.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private OnCompletionListener listener = new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.seekTo(DEFAULT_LOOPING_TIME);
        mp.start();
    }
};
```

Comment: which api your using to perform this task. can you post what you hav tried..

Comment: @TechEnd I am using api 8 (Android 2.2) to perform this task. I am yet to start implementing thing but couldn't get the implementation straight in my head.

Comment: I mean are you using AudioRecord API or MediaPlayer Android API ??? I dint ask about version.

Comment: @TechEnd I am using MediaPlayer

Comment: go to this site http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/ might get some help

Comment: Thans for the link but that is not what I need. I have added the code on the question if you can have a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- play the media from the start .
- Use the onPlaybackFinished event, or
  something similar to start the the media again, this time with the seekTo()
  method

Comment: Tried this but when the sounds get over it leaves a bump in between like no sound for 1 second and then it starts repeating. Any solution for that? I need it to be smooth without stops.

Comment: I have added the code on the question if you can have a look at it.